# Spring - class path resource cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

To tentando subir uma pagina HTML simples no tomcat com spring e thymeleaf, mas quando acesso da o erro:

> An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path
>   resource ..templates/cerveja/CadastroCerveja.html... e também class
>   path resource [templates/cerveja/CadastroCerveja.html] cannot be
>   opened because it does not exist

minha estrutura está assim: src/main/java/webconfig.java

```
    private ITemplateResolver templateResolver() { // class que dita onde fica o template
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        resolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        return resolver;
    }


src/main/java/controller

    @Controller
public class CervejasController {

    @RequestMapping("/cervejas/novo") //Mapeia a URL
    public String novo() {
        return "cerveja/CadastroCerveja";
    }
}
```

e o HTML que estou tetando chamar está em:

`SRC/MAIN/RESOURCE/TEMPLATES/CERVEJA/CadastroCerveja.HTML`

Comment: Pode postar sua pagina html? E se estiver usando Maven, pode postar seu pom.xml?

Comment: O endereço da pasta TEMPLATES está todo em letra maiúscula e no templateResolver está com letras minúsculas. Pode ser isso.